# What is the -update option in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm generating a Haldclut using the below code:

```
 ffmpeg -f lavfi -i haldclutsrc=8 -frames:v 1 hald.png
```

This works well enough, but the cmd line displays a warning informing me that the `hald.png` pattern is invalid, and does not contain a pattern such as `%03d` for an image sequence.

It suggests I should use the `-update` option with `-frames:v 1` if I want a single image.
I'm already using the latter, without the `-update` option, and without issue, but how do I impliment this option to remove the warning.

Comment: Your command does have -update if you add it does the warning go away?

Comment: Tried adding with no success, but not sure where to include it. Also, does it require additional parameters.

Comment: All it does is update the program…

Comment: Can you provide the exact message you received?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `-update 1` just after `-frames:v 1`. But frankly, you can ignore the warning.

`update` is an option specific to the image sequence muxer. It tells the muxer to

1. not expect a variable pattern in the output image filename and instead just create a file with that exact name, and
2. overwrite that file with whatever latest image it is writing.